# Pertaining to Array Lists and the toString Method

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am currently in a Java AP Computer Science class and we have been required to complete an activity that can do the following:

**The class TransactionHistory is used to keep track of a sequence of Transactions. Complete the following definition for this class by providing the body of the toString method, which returns a multiline String consisting of the output from the toString method of each Transaction, each on a new line. (Recall that a String may be broken into multiple lines by including "\n".)
Be careful, though, to ensure that your toString method does not return a String that ends with a newline character. To help you with this, we provide (behind the scenes) a showNewlines method for you to use when testing your toString method. Examine the code inserted by the provided test cases to see how it may be used.**

So far, I have the following code:

```
public class TransactionHistory extends ArrayList<Transaction>
{
  public String toString()
  {
    for (Transaction t : this) {
        return t.toString();
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```

And this is one of the test cases that we are required to use:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    TransactionHistory th = new TransactionHistory();
    th.add( new Deposit( 100.0, "10:15", "10/23/2007" ) );
    th.add( new Deposit( 2.35, "11:05", "9/21/2007" ) );
    th.add( new Withdrawal( 50.0, "2:24", "11/1/2007" ) );
    System.out.println( showNewlines( th.toString() ) );
}
```

With the code that I have currently, all it is capable of doing is printing out the first line of transactions.

Here is what is printed out:

```
Deposit 100.0 10:15 10/23/2007
```

How would I go about making the code print out all of the transactions that were added?

Thank you, all help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at the for loop. Suppose you have 3 transactions, how many times will the body of the loop be executed?

Comment: Shouldn't it loop 3 times?

Comment: It should. But what happens in the first iteration? Are you still in the method then?

Comment: Try stepping through the program execution in a debugger such as IntelliJ Idea. That will show how the program runs, as distinct from your expectations. You'll also learn a super valuable tool.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you guys mean. Right after the first transaction I return it, therefore voiding the rest of the transactions. So, I should append each transaction to a string first, before returning it. Thank you very much! Edit: I used the following code: `for (Transaction t : this) {
        finalResult = finalResult + t.toString() + "\n";
    }
    return finalResult;` yet how would I eliminate the \n at the end of the last string?

Comment: By the way, you should not extend ArrayList, that's not a good pattern. You should declare an ArrayList property inside you TransactionHistory and have an add method that adds to the ArrayList, but not extend ArrayList directly.

Comment: Just treat the last element as a special case and don't append the new line character. Alternatively your can use a 'StringJoiner' in Java8

Comment: @AustinD StringJoiner - nice!

Comment: Okay everyone, thanks for the help! I solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statement is breaking your loop as it already returns the first `Transaction`:

```
    for (Transaction t : this) {
    return t.toString();
    }
```

Use a `StringBuilder` to append each, then return `StringBuilder#toString()`

be careful, the problem indicates that your toString() **DOES NOT RETURN THE STRING THAT ENDS WITH A NEWLINE CHARACTER** which is a different story in itself.

`substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` and `lastIndexOf(String str)` should take care of that.

```
    String a = "foo\nbar\n";
    System.out.println(a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf("\n")));
```

Hope this helps.